# How to write a UNIX script to check if directories contain specified number of files

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a Base Directory that has 4 directories : Dir1 Dir2 Dir3 Dir4. Each of these directories have files in the format: `"Sometext_YYYMMMDD"`. I'm writing a UNIX script to search through the files in all these directories that have a particular string say "`20151215`", and then printing it on the console.

```
find . -name "*20151215" -print
```

Example of files: `File1_20151215` (this will be printed);
`File2_20151214` (this will not be printed)

I want to write a script that runs through these directories and checks if Dir1 contains 4 files with string "20151215", Dir2 contains 3 files with string "20151215" and Dir3 & Dir4 contains 4 files with string "20151215". If the directories don't contain that number of files with that string, then I want to print those directories.

How do I do that? Please help!

**UPDATE:** I have an addition to this: There are also some files that are not in the format `"Sometext_YYYMMMDD"` So, for those I used something like:

`find . -name "FILENAME*" -mtime -1 -exec ls -ltr '{}' \;`

to extract the timestamp when that file was created. But, I want to know how do I add it to the script so that if the timestamp is 15 Dec 2015, then this file should also be counted in the search?

Comment: Related: [Count files in a directory by extension](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the find part, but now you need to count how many files match the pattern.  Since find prints one line per match to the output, you can use "wc -l" to count how many lines there are.  Assign that to a variable, that you can use in a comparison, and you're 90% of the way there.  E.g.

```
d1=$(find ./dir1 -name '*20151215*' | wc -l)
if [ $d1 != 4 ]; then echo "dir1" ; fi
```

For extra credit, you can imagine turning this into a function with inputs of

1. Directory to search
2. Filename pattern to match on
3. How many matches to expect

Which would look like:

```
check_dir () {
  d1=$(find $1 -name "*$2*" | wc -l)
  if [ $d1 != $3 ]; then echo $1 ; fi
}

check_dir ./dir1 20151215 4
check_dir ./dir2 20151215 3
```

Update: with the new requirement to find files based either on the name of the file or the last modification (creation isn't possible), here's two approaches:

The first uses a fairly modern feature of find that isn't available in all versions, newermt:

```
check_dir () {
  d1=$2
  d2=$((d1+1))
  n=$(find $1 \( -name "*$d1*" \) -o \( -newermt $d1 ! -newermt $d2 \) | wc -l)
  if [ $n != $3 ]; then echo $1 ; fi
}

check_dir ./dir1 20151215 4
check_dir ./dir2 20151215 3
```

Which looks a little confusing, but break it down into small steps and it makes sense:

1. d1=$2        # So d1=20151215
2. d2=$((d1+1)) # d2=20151216 (lucky you're specifying the date format this way!)
3. The find command now has two predicates, to match based on the filename or the modification time:

> ```
> \( -name "*$2*" \)    # Matches filenames that contain 20151215
>
> -o                    # Or
>
> \( -newermt $d1 ! -newermt $d2 \)
> ```
>
> The modification time is greater than midnight on the first day, and not greater than midnight on the next day

The second approach uses a couple of temp files, and sets the timestamps on them using the -d option of the touch command

```
#!/bin/bash
check_dir () {
  d1=$2
  d2=$((d1+1))
  f1=`mktemp`
  f2=`mktemp`
  touch -d $d1 $f1
  touch -d $d2 $f2
  n=$(find $1 \( -name "*$d1*" \) -o \( -newer $f1 ! -newer $f2 \) | wc -l)
  if [ $n != $3 ]; then echo $1 "=" $n ; fi
  rm -f $f1 $f2
}
```

Again, it's lucky that the date is in YYYYMMDD since that works with the -d option of the touch command.  If not, you would need to do some string manipulation to get the date into the correct format for "touch -t".

Comment: What if a filename contains a newline?

Comment: Sigh, let's ask the OP how likely that is ;-)

If it's possible, then -print0 | xargs -0 -i "echo aaa" | wc -l

Comment: @IanMcGowan: I just updated my question. There was something more to the filenames that I didn't realise before. Could you help me with that as well please?

Comment: That's actually kind of tricky, depending on the version of find you're using, and just generally because of the way Unix/Linux (mis)handles file creation time stamps.  But I'll update the answer assuming your find has -newermt.

Thank you for calling StackOverflow Tech Support! ;-)

Comment: @IanMcGowan: I get the following error: find: invalid predicate '-newermt' If you want I could give you the format I'm getting my timestamp in after using  mtime. It is : 
-rw-r--r-- 1 usermane esmgroup 4 Dec 16 10:42 ./Dir1/File1_20151215

Comment: IS there a way we could use newer for this?

Comment: @Aksh - yes, if you create two temp files using the touch command with the appropriate time stamps, then you could use `\( -newer $f1 ! -newer $f2 \)`

Comment: @IanMcGowan Could you edit the above script? I'm getting confused as to how to use newer.

Comment: I'm doing something like: check_dir () {
  d1=$2
  d2=$((d1+1))
touch -t 1512200000 temp
  n=$(find $1 \( -name "*$d1*" \) -o \( -newer temp \) | wc -l)
  if [ $n != $3 ]; then echo $1 ; fi
}

check_dir ./dir1 20151215 4
check_dir ./dir2 20151215 3 ; but it's not wroking

Comment: Ok, updated.  Your syntax is right, but I think the time stamp is wrong - rather than 1512200000, it should be 1512150000 - the 15th is *not* newer than the 20th!

Comment: @IanMcGowan I am trying to understand your syntax. So, if I type check_dir ./Dir2 20151221 2; then there should be 2 files in Dir2, which either have 20151521 in their filename or were modified after the midnight of 20151221, but not after the midnight of 20151222? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Also, d1=$2;  d2=$((d1+1)) this won’t work for month/year end dates like 20151231.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work for the last day of the month - we need to leave *something* for you to do ;-)  What have you tried to solve that?  Google "gnu date arithmetic" for some pointers.